# cordova splash screen is not shown

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, phonegap-plugins, splash-screen

I am learning phonegap and cordova now
I want to run the splash screen, but is is not working

This is my config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
```

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />

<name>Test</name>
<description>Hello World App. to learn phonegap :)</description>
<author email="a.elsayed2010@gmail.com">Amira Elsayed Ismail</author>
<content src="index.html" />
<access origin="*" />

<platform name="android">
    <icon src="res/android/icon.png" density="ldpi" />
    <icon src="res/android/icon.png" density="mdpi" />
    <icon src="res/android/icon.png" density="hdpi" />
    <icon src="res/android/icon.png" density="xhdpi" />


    <splash src="res/screen/android/screen.png" density="land-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/android/screen.png" density="land-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/android/screen.png" density="land-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/android/screen.png" density="land-xhdpi"/>

    <splash src="res/screen/android/screen.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/android/screen.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/android/screen.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/android/screen.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>

 </platform>
```

My MainActivity Code

```
   public class MainActivity extends CordovaActivity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.init();
        loadUrl(launchUrl);

    }
}
```

I have already installed the splash screen plugin using the following cmd

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.splashscreen
```

can any one tell me what is the problem here ?

Answer (score 0):

config.xml is in cordova folder, this will not work unless you have res folder in the same directory, that is not a good place to store these images. Normally they are stores under the src directory.

Try to use a relative address and check that folder is correct, using different image resolutions (you are incorrectly using the same image resolution):

For example:

```
<splash density="port-ldpi" src="../src/www/res/screens/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png"/>
<splash density="port-mdpi" src="../src/www/res/screens/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png"/>
<splash density="port-hdpi" src="../src/www/res/screens/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png"/>
<splash density="port-xhdpi" src="../src/www/res/screens/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png"/>
<splash density="land-ldpi" src="../src/www/res/screens/android/screen-ldpi-landscape.png"/>
<splash density="land-mdpi" src="../src/www/res/screens/android/screen-mdpi-landscape.png"/>
<splash density="land-hdpi" src="../src/www/res/screens/android/screen-hdpi-landscape.png"/>
<splash density="land-xhdpi" src="../src/www/res/screens/android/screen-xhdpi-landscape.png"/>
```

[image]